# Little Endian byte storage for character string constants as immediate operands?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, endianness

The processor uses little endian to store bytes in memory

```
mov rax, "bloopers"
mov [s_out], rax
```

In this case what is stored at address `[s_out]` and `[s_out+7]`
and what happens when I print `s_out`

I am quite confused as `rax` will store "bloopers" as "srepoolb".

But I do not know what will happen if you move `rax` into `s_out`. Does it work the same way it does as the register?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've learned:

`mov rax, "bloopers"` stores the string `"bloopers"` in rax but when viewing the memory in little endian format, it appears as `0x737265706f6f6c62`.

`mov [s_out], rax` simply stores the string `"bloopers"` in order. So at memory address `s_out`, it holds the char `b` and at `s_out+7` it holds `s`.

This is documented for NASM in https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.3.  Other assemblers behave similarly for character constants with more than one character.

Thanks @fuz and @Ped7g for helping me.

Comment: The `rax` contains value `0x737265706f6f6c62`. That's not little-endian format, that's 64 bit integer format. You can read that either as "bloopers" or as "srepoolb", depending where you start (low byte or high byte). After you store the qword `0x737265706f6f6c62` value into memory, it will be stored by CPU in little-endian way as bytes `62 6c ...`, i.e. "bloopers". The little-endianness comes to play when you are storing `rax` into memory. While value remains inside CPU only (in `rax`), it has simply 64 bits, no endianness. Other assemblers will NOT behave similarly, NASM is sort of exception

Comment: generally "mov rax,<string>" doesn't make sense in assembly, so that's why the assembler-specific rules will apply to such source line. The x86 CPU has only similar instructions like `mov rax,imm64` which requires 64 bit constant. So the assembler has to decide, how it will convert "string" into 64 bits, some will report error, others may convert it on per byte basis, resulting in value `0x626c6f6f70657273`, which after storing it into memory will form string "srepoolb". Generally everything syntax related in assembly is assembler specific, even for same CPU target.

Comment: @Ped7g That's not entirely correct.  The value still has endianess as you can see by inspecting its parts through `eax`, `ax`, `ah`, and `al`.  All your comment does is turning what little clarity X3Gamma has found into even more confusion.

Comment: @fuz `al` is low 8 bits, and low 8 bits of `0x737265706f6f6c62` is `0x62`. It's more about the way how you write the numbers, than endianness. Even if the x86 would be big-endian, the `rax` would be still `0x737265706f6f6c62` and `al` is still `0x62`.

Comment: @Ped7g Further note that gas in fact behaves the same way wrt. character literals comprising multiple characters.  I think many C compilers do so, too.